Google Slides API: How to fit a text into a textbox
Since AutoFit isn’t functioning in the API, I’m working on developing a custom function to calculate a font size that fits text within the textbox. However, the results are inconsistent, and I haven’t yet found an effective solution.
Here is the function, I'm working on:
function calculateTextFit($boxWidth, $boxHeight, $text, $fontSizeStartPT, $ScaleX, $ScaleY)
    {
        // (AgendaSlide, TitleSlide 1.2)
        $fontAdjustmentFactor = $fontSizeStartPT > 26 ? 1.2 : 1.1;

        $minFontSize = $this->ptToPixels(8) * $ScaleY;
        $maxFontSize = $this->ptToPixels($fontSizeStartPT) * $ScaleY;
        $lineSpacing = $this->ptToPixels(1.4) * $ScaleY;

        $boxWidth = $this->emuToPixels($boxWidth) * $ScaleX; // Масштабування по X
        $boxHeight = $this->emuToPixels($boxHeight) * $ScaleY; // Масштабування по Y

        $areaSize = $boxWidth * $boxHeight;
        preg_match_all('/(\n|\r|\n\n)/', $text, $matches);
        $totalLineBreaks = count($matches[0]);

        // is this an Asian language (Chinese, Korean, Japanese)?
        $hasAsianCharacters = preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{3040}-\x{30FF}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}]/u', $text);
        $textLen = mb_strlen($text);

        for ($fontSize = $maxFontSize; $fontSize >= $minFontSize; $fontSize--) {

            $fontWidth = $hasAsianCharacters ? $fontSize : $fontSize * $fontAdjustmentFactor ;
            $textSize = $textLen * $fontWidth * $fontSize * $lineSpacing;
            $textSize = $textSize + ($totalLineBreaks * $lineSpacing * $boxWidth);

            if ($textSize <= $areaSize) {
                $newFontSize = $this->pixelsToPt($fontSize);
                return $newFontSize < 5 ? 5 : $newFontSize;
            }
        }

        return $this->pixelsToPt($minFontSize);
    }

